# Outputting Union-Jack-like ASCII Art with Java

Tags: algorithm, ascii

I was given an assignment to code an algorithm outputting (in a plain ASCII, no fancy drawings), for a given K, a KxK square with the lines of symmetry as x and other things as o. If K is even, though, we use two lines of x'es to mark the horizontal and vertical line of symmetry. Moreover, we can't use more than two loops in the whole source.

So I have two ideas. The first is to analyze the coordinates each of the points should fulfill - there should be an equation for each of the points telling us if a given (Kx, Ky) point is x or o. We put it in the alternation of some if and just while-loop through all possible (Kx, Ky) marking some spots as x and others as y. This requires one loop.

The other idea, quite brute-force but not making us analyze all the points, is to have a set of variables we then use for concatenating the strings. Let me explain: we have one while loop checking the "height" variable (each turn we decrement it by one) inside which we use a custom method of some repeatString consisting of one while-loop as well (it just multiplies the string by given t times). So we have something like this:

```
while(height):
if height==maxHeight OR ==0: print repeatString("x", maxWidth)
else if height is an element of markedKy (an array telling us which Ky's to mark as x'es as the whole): print repearString("x", maxWidth)
else print "x"+(howManySpaces*" ")+"x" ["xx" if even] + (howManySpaces*" ") +"x"
```

...and so on. What I write above is of course very loose and does not cover many cases (in fact , it does quite a little), but I think it may make my concept less confusing. This second method, however, would be a real pain to code - I can see just now how bug-prone it is.

Is there any third, best method? I'm cracking my head on this, though it seems so easy, and can't figure out anything else.

Comment: please refrain from using the `homework` tag, it is being phased out

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry and thanks :)

Comment: How are the "o"s determined? They cannot simply fill all the spaces that shouldn't be "x"s, since i see you also have " "s...

Answer (score 0):

I can do it using only a SINGLE loop... ;-)

```
input K
half := K / 2 , square := K * K
for pixel = 0; pixel < square; ++pixel
    horiz := pixel % K , vert := pixel / K
    if horiz = vert or horiz + vert + 1 = K // the diagonals
            or horiz = half or horiz = K - 1 - half // the middle vertical line(s)
            or vert = half or vert = K - 1 - half // the middle horizontal line(s)
        output "x"
    else if ShouldBeO(horiz + 1, vert + 1)
        output "o"
    else
        output " "
    if horiz = K - 1 // add "and vert < K - 1" if you don't want the last EOL
        output EndOfLine
end for
```